# css word-wrap: break-word won't work

Tags: html, css

I have two inline span. code sample:

```
    <div class="comment_content">

        <span class="comment_author"><?= $child_comment['comment_author'] ?></span>
        <span class="comment_text"><?= $child_comment['comment_content'] ?></span>

    </div>
```

And scss sample:

```
.comment_content {        
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.comment_author {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.comment_text {            
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If my expected view has to be: [image: Expected result]

If user enters string without spaces, string won't break. And breaks design: [image: Problem]

How properly break long words ??

Comment: Please try to minimize the width percentage or put the width in pixel

Answer (score 34):

`white-space: nowrap` will prevent `word-break` from taking effect. Some templates apply `white-space: nowrap` which necessitates overriding this attribute with `white-space: normal`.

Comment: `white-space: break-spaces;` preserves empty lines, might be worth considering. [MDN has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) a nice playground for `white-space` attribute

Answer (score 21):

To properly break long-words it requires to combine several CSS properties, I would suggest defining and applying helper class like this:

```
.break-long-words {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

Properties explained:

- **overflow-wrap** and **word-wrap** are [aliases](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#overflow-wrap-property) for same thing but some browsers support one and not the other so we need them both. They
  are offical "correct" way to break words but they don't have any effect on elements with dynamic width so we need more...
- **word-break** is originally intended for requiring a particular behaviour with CJK (Chinese, Japanese, and Korean) text but works similar to
  word-wrap but in WebKit break-all value breaks everything and everywhere. For that reason we must use non-standard and poorly
  documented WebKit-only break-word value.
- and optionally, if it makes sense for break words to have hypens (ie. for URLs it probably doesn't) we can use hypens in browsers that
  support them (at the moment Firefox, Safari, Edge and IE 10+). Also note that in Firefox hypens don't work if you have word-brake
  property so unless you have fixed-width container you must choose between hypens on FF or legacy support.

Note that I omitted vendor prefixes but if you don't use something like Autoprefixer than this is full verison:

```
.break-long-words {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

Comment: There is no such value "break-word" for the property "word-break".  In any case, you're assigning two values to this property, so the second one will override the first one.

Comment: As I explained: word-break: break-word is webkit-only property intended to override break-all in browsers that use webkit. Reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/#article-header-id-0

Comment: Does this follow break-word first > break-all > hyphens in priority as in terms of availability of the keyword?

Comment: `word-break: break-all` is going to override any `word-wrap` you set, so there's no reason to have both. Furthermore, it'll leave word fragments at the end of any line that still has space for text, and break words that could have just been moved to the next line. This solution needs some work.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) style to define *where* in the word to break to the next line. By default, it uses spaces or hyphens but you can set it to `break-all` to allow breaking on any letter:

```
.comment_text {
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @ManoVardasRamūnas unfortunately, you can't really have it both ways.

Comment: maybe i will use Javascript for this

Comment: There's no reason to set word-wrap if you're going to use `word-break: break-all`.

Answer (score 1):

I thing it will be helpful. You have to specify `width`, particular in your case.

```css
.comment_content{
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.comment_author{
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.comment_text{
  width: 400px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment_content">

        <span class="comment_author">Hello</span>
        <span class="comment_text">qeqweqweqweqeeqeqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqeqweqweqweqweqweqweqwewqeqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqeqeqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqweqeqewqweqeq</span>

    </div>
```

Here is a working examples to achieve what you want: [examples](https://jsfiddle.net/Mirodil/qc38ky3v/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
word-break: break-all;
```

See fiddle here

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/ap7fs92h/)

Comment: for long string it is good solution, but it breaks all words.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `word-break: break-all;` in `.comment_content` class.