# Paragraph text overflowing off page

Tags: html, css

On my website I have a page which lists podcasts - when this page is viewed on a small screen text is overflowing off the page:

[image: Text overflowing]

[This Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36555643/6296447) answer suggests creating a css class with properties which should stop text overflowing, like this:

```
.break-long-words {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

I've checked in Chrome Dev tools and the `break-long-words` class is being applied to the text, but the text is still going off the page

Comment: Show us the markup and the CSS: create an MCVE that reproduces your issue. If the text is being offset using CSS transforms or using cardinal positions, their widths might not be computed the way you think they would be, causing them to visually overflow the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Text on the web *always reflows by default*, so the behaviour you have is most likely because the size of one of the containers of that text is fixed. Fixed at a size larger than the mobile viewport in this case.

It could also be that there are `&nbsp;`, non-breaking spaces between the words in that copy. Naturally, they are space elements that prevent breaking and therefore stick the words together preventing them from reflowing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. None of the containers are fixed that I can see. 

If you are able could you visit this page https://devpodcasts.net/podcasts/tagged/java which if you resize it you will see how text is flowing off the page.

It is a possibility that there are `&nbsp;` spaces in the text as it is coming from an RSS feed but I am not entirely sure this is the reason.

Comment: I have viewed your site, and the podcast shown in your post is fine. I can't reproduce your issue at all; text is reflowing as expected.